# Php 7.3 is installed, but phpenmod pgsql says php 7.2

Tags: php

I installed php 7.3 for Postgres 10 about 2-3 months ago, but I had to stop there due to other projects and now I am starting to use php for Postgres.

I had previously installed php 7.2, so after the 7.3 installation I issued these commands from Putty:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

That worked.  Now I need to install pdo for php.  To check, I issued this command from Putty:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-pgsql is already the newest version     (2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3).
The following package was automatically installed and is no     longer required:
  grub-pc-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
```

Okay, so it confirms that php 7.3 is installed.  Now I issued this command from Putty:

```
sudo phpenmod pgsql
```

Putty echoed back:

```
WARNING: Module pgsql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module pgsql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
```

But wait – I have already switched from php 7.2 to php 7.3.  Why do I get "doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available."  It should say 7.3, not 7.2.

Why do I get this warning (that it doesn’t exist in 7.2) when my default is now 7.3?  I confirmed that pgsql ini file does exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available.

My ultimate goal is to install pdo for php 7.3, but I’m confused about what steps to take next.  When I issue phpenmod pgsql, it warns me about 7.2, but I have 7.3 enabled.  Do I not need to issue the command sudo phpenmod pgsql to install and use pdo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `sudo apt install php7.3-common`

Comment: That installed a lot of things, so it looks like the right direction.  But now when I issue "a2enmod pgsql" I get "module pgsql does not exist."  What next?

Comment: install `php7.3-pgsql`

Comment: Says "php7.3-pgsql is already the newest version."  Does it need to be enabled before I install / enable pdo?

Answer (score 2):

`phpenmod` enables a module for all available sapis and php versions by default, it just means you don't have it installed for 7.2. That's also why you see the warning twice, once for the `cli` sapi and once for `mod_php`.

You can pass the specific php version with the flag `-v`: `phpenmod -v 7.3 pgsql` but the warning is purely informational and should enable the module for the versions for which it is available.

Or you could install the module for 7.2 too, in case you need to switch versions `apt install php7.2-pgsql`.

Comment: That didn't return any error messages, it just went back to the command line, so I guess it worked.  Followup question:  I previously edited php.ini in /etc/php/7.3/apache2 and removed the semicolons in front of extension=pdo_pgsql and extension=pgsql.  Do I need to do that to the same file in in /etc/php/7.3/cli?  My ultimate goal is to enable the pdo driver so I can use pdo.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't, that's the point of `phpenmod`, it does that for you. Look under `/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/pgsql.ini`, it has the same `extension` line, right? When enabling the module, it links it to `/etc/php/version/mods-enabled` and all those files get included in the main config.

Comment: It looks like I'm okay now because I just issued the command php -i PDO and got a huge listing; two lines say: PDO support => enabled and PDO drivers => pgsql.  Another line says "PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled."  Now I'll test it and look in my apache log file