# PHP ZIP extension is installed but not loading in PHP project

Tags: php, apache, zip, ubuntu-16.04, php-extension

In my localserver zip extension is installed and showing when running php --ini from terminal. I am using ubuntu 16.04

```
 php --ini
 PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
 Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
 Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
 Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
 Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
 /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
 /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
 ...
 ...
 /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
 /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
 /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zmq.ini
```

but i am trying to install espocrm, when i'm installing it showing

```
  PHP Error: Extension zip is not found.
```

below id zip.ini file location -

```
  1/mods-available/zip.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/
  (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.4/mods-available$ sudo phpenmod zipWARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  WARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.4/mods-available$ cd /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.2/mods-available$ ls
   calendar.ini  gd.ini        mysqlnd.ini    shmop.ini      wddx.ini
   ctype.ini     gettext.ini   opcache.ini    simplexml.ini  xml.ini
   curl.ini      iconv.ini     pdo.ini        sockets.ini     xmlreader.ini
   dom.ini       json.ini      pdo_mysql.ini  sysvmsg.ini      xmlwriter.ini
   exif.ini      mbstring.ini  phar.ini       sysvsem.ini    xsl.ini
   fileinfo.ini  mcrypt.ini    posix.ini      sysvshm.ini    zip.ini
   ftp.ini       mysqli.ini    readline.ini   tokenizer.ini  zmq.ini
   (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.2/mods-available$ cp /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/zip.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/zip.ini
   cp: not writing through dangling symlink '/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/zip.ini'
   (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.2/mods-available$ sudo phpenmod zipWARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  WARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.2/mods-available$ sudo phpenmod zip
  WARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  WARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
  (base) user_dead@never-settle:/etc/php/7.2/mods-available$
```

What i am missing?

Comment: Extensions for `cli` and other sapis are loaded independently. Try running `phpenmod zip` to try and enable it for all of them. Alternatively, create a php file with `phpinfo();` on it and access it trough your server to check what extensions are loaded.

Comment: @msg   I tried this its showing  `WARNING: Module zip ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available` , but i'm using php 7.4 and in php/7.4/mods-available/ already have zip.ini

Comment: That command enables the module [for all sapis *and* versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384969#57385382). You must have 7.2 installed too, even if you are not using it. Check if it's enabled under the corresponding sapi `/etc/php/7.4/SAPI/mods-enabled/` with SAPI being either `apache2` or `fpm`.

Comment: Thankyou @msg bro all done. actually i have amost of php versions installed and currently 7.4 and also zip extension is enabled in 7.4 but my project is choosing 7.2 and looking zip in this version. now i installed php7.2-zip and all working fine,Thank you. You helped me lot in clearing this